# Angular: x/y position of cursor in contented

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I get the x/y position of my input character in a contenteditable div?

I want to show an overlay with some infos below the input char and so I need to know the position to place the overlay to the position below the input char.

```
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 400px; height: 400px;"
  contenteditable="true" (input)="input ($event)"></div>
```

Comment: It seems to me that one of solutions currently used is to superpose a hidden container with exact same style, and portion of text before the caret into it. Then check for width and height.

Comment: Not sure I understand how this would help me.

Comment: To clarify, below the input you would like to display the x, y position of the character relative to the document?

Comment: Coordinates I need to place the overlay near the input character. The content of the overlay is not important here I think.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://jh3y.medium.com/how-to-where-s-the-caret-getting-the-xy-position-of-the-caret-a24ba372990a